# How to create auto popup window in android studio

Tags: android, popupwindow

I wanted to create an auto pop up window at the first page in the app. But I couldn't seem to find any tutorials online. Anyone please guide. Any help will appreciate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void openDialog(View view){
  AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
  alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure,You wanted to make decision");

  alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You clicked yes button",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
  });

  alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        finish();
     }
  });

  AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
  alertDialog.show();
```

}

Just call this method openDialog(); after your  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Example

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
openDialog();
```

Comment: However, instead of yes and no, I like it to have just one option like dismiss, how can I do that

Comment: just use poisitive button. remove negative button code. it will show single button. and make text whatever you want